# Restrict users from entering special characters and numbers only

Tags: javascript

I am using this regular expression:

```
/^[a-z,A-Z ]+$/i.test( value );
```

i need to restrict only special and numeric at a time.
`mango123#@` should be allowed, but `&^%123` should not.

Comment: The regular expression you have would match an entire string that only contains upper or lower-case letters and commas, because of the `^` and `$` anchors. I think based on the examples you've given your requirement can be summarised as: "The value must contain at least one upper or lower-case letter". Is that correct?

Comment: 9999 should not allow ,but mango 9999 should be allowed

Comment: What about "9999 mango"? Should that be allowed? You need to narrow down the specific rules for what does and doesn't match before you can write a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex https://regex101.com/r/bX1dO3/1

```
 /^[a-z,A-Z ].*$/i
```